# What would be the best way to group my data that is based on monthly columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So basically, I'm making a report that shows the max price for all products for any given month, from Jan to Jul.  Ideally, I would like 1 row per PartNo and for it to show the max price from month to month.  Here's my code and photo of result below:

```
SELECT
    pd.PartNo,
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 1 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN MAX(pd.UnitCost)
        END AS [Jan 2018],
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 2 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN MAX(pd.UnitCost)
        END AS [Feb 2018],
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 3 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN MAX(pd.UnitCost)
        END AS [Mar 2018],
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 4 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN MAX(pd.UnitCost)
        END AS [Apr 2018],
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 5 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN MAX(pd.UnitCost)
        END AS [May 2018],
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 6 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN MAX(pd.UnitCost)
        END AS [Jun 2018],
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 7 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN MAX(pd.UnitCost)
        END AS [Jul 2018]
FROM PODet pd
    JOIN PO p ON pd.PONum = p.PONum
    JOIN Estim e ON pd.PartNo = e.PartNo
WHERE p.DateEnt > '20180101'
GROUP BY pd.PartNo, p.DateEnt
ORDER BY pd.PartNo, p.DateEnt DESC
```

[image]

So if you look at the results and look at let's say PartNo CAB-01, you can see that not only is it not grouping across columns, but within the same month itself, it's also not grouping.  What am I doing wrong?  Thx in advance

Comment: Looks like a job for `PIVOT`

Comment: It IS grouping exactly as you told it to, you just told it to group by the part number and the Exact Date. CAB-01 was handled on 2 different dates in July, so it gets two rows.  Remove `p.dateEnt` from your group by and order by, and add `MAX()` around all your `CASE` statements, and you should get what you want.

Comment: Than @Hellion, that worked great

Comment: @Hellion you should make that an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd like to have one row per part number, but in your `GROUP BY` clause you told it to produce one row per unique date that each part number entry occurs on:  `GROUP BY Pd.PartNo, Pd.DateEnt`.  The CAB-01 item apparently has two different dates in July associated with it, so it has two rows with values under 'Jul 2018'; you just can't tell that they're for two different dates because the exact date is not part of the output.

To get what you want, you need to remove `Pd.DateEnt` from your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses, and move your `MAX()` from the inside to the outside of your `CASE` statements so that the `GROUP BY` is still valid:

```
SELECT
pd.PartNo,
MAX(CASE
    WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 1 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN pd.UnitCost
    END) AS [Jan 2018],
MAX(CASE
    WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 2 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN pd.UnitCost
    END) AS [Feb 2018],
MAX(CASE
    WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 3 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN pd.UnitCost
    END) AS [Mar 2018],
MAX(CASE
    WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 4 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN pd.UnitCost
    END) AS [Apr 2018],
MAX(CASE
    WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 5 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN pd.UnitCost
    END) AS [May 2018],
MAX(CASE
    WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 6 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN pd.UnitCost
    END) AS [Jun 2018],
MAX(CASE
    WHEN MONTH(p.DateEnt) = 7 AND YEAR(p.DateEnt) = 2018 THEN pd.UnitCost
    END) AS [Jul 2018]
FROM PODet pd
    JOIN PO p ON pd.PONum = p.PONum
    JOIN Estim e ON pd.PartNo = e.PartNo
WHERE p.DateEnt > '20180101'
GROUP BY pd.PartNo
ORDER BY pd.PartNo
```

Also, you're not using the ESTIM table at all in the query as shown, so you may want to take that JOIN out; and if you want to include ALL of 2018, you should change your `WHERE` condition to `WHERE p.DateEnt >= '20180101'`.